# Update timestamp when saving

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

I re-worked a bit the solution for creating a timestamp [in a previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46586/how-can-i-timestamp-a-notebook)

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookEventActions :> {"WindowClose" :> 
    Module[{dy, mn, yr}, {dy, mn, yr} = 
      Map[(LinkWrite[First[$FrontEnd], FrontEnd`Value[#]];
         LinkRead[First[$FrontEnd]]) &, {"Day", "MonthName", 
        "Year"}]; NotebookLocate["LastModified"];
     NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
      Cell[TextData[{"Last modified:  ", dy, ", ", mn, " ", yr}], 
       "Text", CellTags -> "LastModified"]]]}]
```

As one can see, the action is done when one closes the notebook. I would like it however to do it whenever I save the document (normally via Ctrl+S). I did not find a convenient tag like `Save` to replace `WindowsClose`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you can use `{"MenuCommand", "Save"}`

Comment: Doing that indeed updates the timestamp, however it does not seem to actually save the notebook at all anymore!

Comment: Add PassEventsDown->True

Comment: Thanks! This now works like a charm!

Comment: Patrick, self-answers are encouraged here; perhaps you could summarize the advice you got in comments in an answer of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Carl Woll, the following code does the trick,

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookEventActions :> {{"MenuCommand", "Save"} :> 
    Module[{dy, mn, yr}, {dy, mn, yr} =
      Map[(LinkWrite[First[$FrontEnd], FrontEnd`Value[#]]; 
         LinkRead[First[$FrontEnd]]) &, {"Day", "MonthName", 
        "Year"}];
     NotebookLocate["LastModified"];
     NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
      Cell[TextData[{"Last modified:  ", dy, ", ", mn, " ", yr}], 
       "Text", CellTags -> "LastModified"]]], PassEventsDown -> True}]
```